# Pure javascript modal does not show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxLdgz) on my project. I've copied the html, css, javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
            document.getElementById('show').onclick = function() {
                dialog.show();
            };
            document.getElementById('exit').onclick = function() {
                dialog.close();
            };
        </script>
        <style>
            dialog {
                width: 500px;
                background:black;
                border: 1px solid #dadada;
                font-family:sans-serif;
                padding: 5px 10px 20px 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dialog id="window">
            <h3>Sample Dialog!</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, inventore!</p>
            <button id="exit">Close Dialog</button>
        </dialog>
        <button id="show">Show Dialog</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately when I click on the "Show Dialog" button nothing happens.

Comment: Use your console. This clearly defines the issue: TypeError: dialog.show is not a function index.html:24:8
TypeError: dialog.close is not a function index.html:27:8
TypeError: dialog.show is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `javascript` code in `window.onload` to make sure `DOM` is ready before manipulating it as follows:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
    document.getElementById('show').onclick = function() {
        dialog.show();
    };
    document.getElementById('exit').onclick = function() {
        dialog.close();
    };
};
```